# How to show Unanswered question filtered by bounty request?

Tags: support, bounties, unanswered-questions, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144952/how-to-search-only-unanswered-questions-with-an-open-bounty)

How to show or search **Unanswered** question `filtered by` **bounty** request?
In case of programmer want to raising up the reputation by finding the best answer to hope to get the bounty, this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is hasnotice:1 answers:0 closed:0, which will include many posts with a bounty notice. see: [How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144952/how-to-search-only-unanswered-questions-with-an-open-bounty)