# How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties, unanswered-questions

Is there a way to search only ***unanswered questions*** with an open bounty on StackOverflow ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search for bounty questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of the date of this post, there isn't a way to filter on whether or not a question has a bounty on it.

The closest you can get is `hasnotice:1 answers:0 closed:0`, which will include some extra posts with a notice.

See the clickable Advanced Search Tips on the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for more options.

---

I should add that maybe you don't want to be doing this. Just because a bountied question has an answer it doesn't mean that it is *answered*. I've received a bounty before when 3 answers were posted before mine.

Comment: thanks! thanks helps. I'm not familiar enough with the system to know what "hasnotice" conflates with hasbounty. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like this still works after the search update earlier this month. Nice!

Comment: I think something's changed behind the scenes: `hasnotice` gets me nothing in the way of questions with bounties