# Finding featured questions without answer

Tags: support, search, bounties, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144952/how-to-search-only-unanswered-questions-with-an-open-bounty)

Is there a search method for finding questions without a single answer and has a bounty/featured?

Thanks

Comment: You can write a user script to do that.

Comment: like what? any example?

Comment: An **unrelated** example: http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts

Comment: There aren't that many featured questions that you can't just go to the featured page and page through.

Comment: in stackoverflow, there is 28 pages.

Comment: For me, there are 9. Cause I show more than 15 questions per page. =>

Comment: good trick ;) Thanks :)